# How to apply external css only into specific area

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a web app which must have an option to see an area with Bootstrap4.1 or Bootstrap3. All app is developed with Bootstrap3:
[image: Exmaple]

I have logic implemented to switch between BT4 and BT3

But when I insert the Bootstrap4 all page is affected.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

How can I apply Bootstrap4.1 only into specific area?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. You've got some work to do.

- First download Bootstrap 4's source files and open the `bootstrap.scss` file.
- Enclose the whole CSS with a class-name of your choice.

Example:

```
.your_class_name {
  /*Source files*/
}
```

Now you have an SCSS file.

- Then go to this [link](http://www.cssportal.com/scss-to-css/) and copy paste your code and convert it to CSS file.

You'll notice that all the Bootstrap's classes have be preceded with your class name.

- Copy that file to your project.

In the HTML code, whenever you want to use the Bootstrap 4 classes, simply start with

`<div class="your_class_name">` and enclose your contents in it.

Bootstrap 4's classes will be applied only to the enclosed div's children.

Comment: Remember me? @allan
Nice and clean answer! :)

Comment: Of course I remember :D Ping me soon. Same name on Facebook and Twitter @samuellawrentz